# Spring Boot 406 status code for PUT Request

Tags: java, spring-boot, put, http-status-code-406

Code is

```
@RestController
@Component
@Slf4j
public class ServicesController {
 @CrossOrigin
    @PutMapping(
            consumes = "multipart/form-data",
            path = "/{id}/{route}/structure_article/{filename:.+}")
    public ResponseEntity<ServiceResponse> updateStructureXMLFile(
            @PathVariable("id") final String id,
            @PathVariable("route") final String route,
            @RequestParam("file") final MultipartFile uploadfile,
            @PathVariable("filename") final String fileName) throws IOException {
(Some processing)
return new ResponseEntity<>(response, httpHeaders, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
}
```

**Here response is a POJO with public getters and setters.**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/baben.png)

When I am putting a file getting this error:

```
{
    "timestamp": 1596783608973,
    "status": 406,
    "error": "Not Acceptable",
    "exception": "org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException",
    "message": "Could not find acceptable representation",
    "path": "/7f3033d7-3979-45e0-9f0a-172b60568edb/articles/structure_article/manuscript.xml"
}
```

What can be solution for this?
Thank  you

Comment: Are you sure that this is the correct Controller? Because this path "/{id}/{route}/structure_article/{filename:.+}" don't look like the one on the image

Comment: And what is the request ?? Aspecially `Accept` header. And yeah, request is made to different endpoint than specified here (missing structure_rticle)

Comment: I have edited the image

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the [Content Negotiation](https://spring.io/blog/2013/05/11/content-negotiation-using-spring-mvc) was configured like:

```
@Override
public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer
        .favorPathExtension(true)
        .defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .mediaType("xml", MediaType.APPLICATION_XML) 
        .mediaType("json", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON); 
}
```

and just like you, I have a controller method with

```
@PutMapping("/user/{userId:.+}")
```

So, Spring tries to treat a request `/user/email@domain.com` for example with the `Content-Type` of `.com` file extension which does not exist in the [Common MIME types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types), hence the 406 error.

I resolved it by turning off `favorPathExtension`.